# Google Earth Engine- error 'Cannot export array bands.' When exporting file from assets to drive as Geotiff?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I ran temporalsegmentationccdc algorithm and saved output in the GEE assets. There is an output file in the asset but when I tried to export that output file from the assets to drive I am getting an error such as

'Error: Cannot export array bands.'

The output file is of 35 bands and I have tried to export each band individually but I am still getting the same error. I have not yet found any solution for this error.
Has anyone got a similar error when exporting files from GEE Assets to Drive? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Here is my export code:

```
var temporalSeg_band1 = image_temporalSeg.select(['blue_coefs'])

Map.addLayer(image_temporalSeg)

var aoi = image

// export the image to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ee.Image(temporalSeg_band1), 
  description: "Band_blue_coeffecient",
  folder: "GEE_data",
  fileNamePrefix: "Blue_coef",
  scale: 30,
  region: aoi,
  maxPixels: 10000000,
  shardSize: 100,
  fileDimensions: 5000,
  crs: "EPSG:3338",
  fileFormat: "GeoTIFF"
})
```